# Typescript recursion of promises

Tags: typescript, recursion, promise

I need to run multiple queries on a DB that depend on each other (before second one I need result of first one etc).
The database describes a folder structure, so the call pattern is a tree-like structure (root is first, then come branches etc.).
Before going ahead in the code I want to guarantee that all queries are done. The queries (sqlite3) are asyncronous.

Here is a (non-working) dummy code that models the stuff. I replaced the query with a setTimeout() function.

```js
var array: Array<Number> = [];

const f = (iDepth: number): Array<Promise<any>> => {
    const pa = [];

    array.push(iDepth);
    if (iDepth > 1) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            pa.push(
                new Promise((resolve) => {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        Promise.all(f(iDepth - 1)).then((prom) => {
                            return prom;
                        });
                    }, 1);

                    //return resolve(f(iDepth-1));
                })
            );
        }
    } else {
        return [Promise.resolve()];
    }

    console.log(pa);
    return pa;
};

Promise.all(f(4)).then(() => {
    console.log("***");
    console.log(array);
});
```

Where is the error?
Note that I'm a TS noob.

Comment: What is the error? What are you trying to do? What's the shape of the data you're traversing? "*I replaced the query with a setTimeout() function.*" note that it's generally a bad idea, since `setTimeout` does not return a promise. And you also never resolve your promise, either.

Comment: Can you show the actual code, please? It's really unclear how these queries depend on each other. If each one depends on the previous' results, and they run sequentially, you should not be building an array of promises (or use `Promise.all`) anywhere.

Comment: HI, the acutal code is quite a mess and this is the reason I wrote this dummy code. The database queries are sqlite3's, like, each() and other similar functions ( https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API ) and use callbacks like setTimeout() does, this is why I replaced stuff with it. However if I can force all the things into a syncronous working is OK for me. @Bergi this is why I used Promise.all() all around.

Comment: Then please try to refactor the sqlite stuff into a helper function (which you then can mock with the `setTimeout`), but you still need to show us what data you are passing into this helper function that comes from the previous query result.

Answer (score 0):

This is what seems to be a working solution: converting a function with a callback into a Promise. I handled only the happy path (resolve).

```
var array:Array<Number> = [];

const f = (iDepth:number):Array<Promise<any>> => {
    const pa = [];

    array.push(iDepth);
    if (iDepth > 1) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            pa.push(new Promise((resolve) =>{
                setTimeout(() => {
                    return resolve(Promise.all(f(iDepth-1)));
                }, 100);
            }));
        }
    }
    return pa;
};

Promise.all(f(4)).then(() => {
    console.log('***Finished***')
    console.log(array);
})
```

Note that I'm still unsure that on a conceptual level it's a good solution or a professional frontender would approach the whole thing differently.

Also note that I could remove the inner selector's else branch and stuff still worked.

Comment: PS also note that I feel to use 'resolve' word quite randomly at line 11. But worked.